# Magento Bug: Name column empty in Customer Super Attribute/Product Grid

Tags: magento

[image: missing name column]

On initial load, the values for the column name are blank and only contain a `&nbsp;`

I did some debugging and the file that is the problem is here:
`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config/Grid.php`

Inside the _prepareCollection method, there is a block of code that is suppose to add the name attribute to the filter:

```
$product = $this->_getProduct();
$collection = $product->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id',$product->getAttributeSetId())
    ->addFieldToFilter('type_id', $allowProductTypes)
    ->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
```

But the resulting query mentions nothing about the name:

```
SELECT `e`.*, (
    IF(
        IF(
            cataloginventory_stock_item.use_config_manage_stock,
            1,
            cataloginventory_stock_item.manage_stock
        ), 
        cataloginventory_stock_item.is_in_stock,
        1
    )
) AS `is_saleable`, `cataloginventory_stock_item`.`is_in_stock` AS `inventory_in_stock`, `_table_color`.`value` AS `color`, `_table_size`.`value` AS `size` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` ON (cataloginventory_stock_item.product_id=e.entity_id)
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `_table_color` ON (`_table_color`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`_table_color`.`attribute_id` = '80') AND (`_table_color`.`store_id` = 0)
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `_table_size` ON (`_table_size`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`_table_size`.`attribute_id` = '123') AND (`_table_size`.`store_id` = 0) WHERE (e.attribute_set_id = '9') AND (((e.type_id = 'simple') or (e.type_id = 'virtual') or (e.type_id = 'downloadable'))) AND (((e.required_options != '1') or (e.required_options is NULL))) AND (_table_color.value not in ('')) AND (_table_size.value not in (''))
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Go here:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config/Simple.php
```

and comment out the following line:

```
//$attribute->setAttributeCode('simple_product_' . $attributeCode);
```

I have to be honest, I'm not sure why that line was added, so please test to make sure it has no implications elsewhere